# Ext JS Events not firing but I can't see why

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, keydown

I am using a Ext.tree.Panel derived object to simulate a menu navigation bar. My objective is to have the user tab around the screen and arrive at the menu, at which point the user can use the up/down/left/right keys to navigate the menu in a similar way that you can use the keyboard to navigate around the tree panel in Windows explorer.

It all displays fine but I cannot get hold of the keyboard events. Well, it sometimes triggers after lots of up and downs but I expect to get it straight away. I know the event is being handled in ExtJS as I've seen it arrive in the publish function that fire's it to all interested objects. It just doesn't get routed to my handler. Any ideas why not? Here is the code where I set up my handlers. I've put them in the afterrender in case it was a timing problem with the element not yet being created.

```
Ext.define('CSSL.view.menubar.Menubar', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
xtype: 'menubar',

controller: 'menubar',
viewModel: {
    type: 'menubar'
},

listeners: {
    afterrender: function (comp, eOpts) {
        var el = comp.getTargetEl();
        el.on('keydown', function (e, comp, x) {
            console.log(e.type + ' [in menu]\r\n');
        }, comp);
        el.dom.addEventListener('keydown', function (e, comp, x) {
            console.log(e.type + ' [in menu]\r\n');
        });
    },
    beforeselect: 'onSelectionChange',
    focus: 'onFocus',
    blur: 'onBlur'
    //itemkeyup: 'onItemKeyUp',
},
rootVisible: false,
```

and so on through the rest of the code. Interestingly, adding the event listener directly to the Dom element handler (addEventListener) does work and does so consistently. I'd just like to know what is going on as I'd rather use the ExtJS handler system than the base javascript.

Thanks